# Как в диалоговом окне узнать id инпута, по клику на который оно было открыто?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Диалоговое окно вызывается кликом по инпуту. Как мне в диалоговом окне определить id инпута из которого оно было вызвано?
Тоесть нужен такой функционал: `document.getElementById("oldtag").value = val;`, только без указания `id` инпута вручную. Надо чтобы само определяло, так как будут еще инпуты с другими `id`, которые используют это же диалоговое окно

Подключение диалогового окна:

```
<div style='display:none;' id='select_tag'>
    <?php require_once __DIR__.'/../tag/_tag.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Форма, по клику на которую открывается диалоговое окно:

```
<input id="oldtag" name="Tag[name]" onclick="$('#select_tag').dialog('open');" value="<?=$model_tag->name?>"  type="text" required/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте дополнительный объект, который будет хранить `id` нажатого элемента. Всем элементам, для которых нужен вызов диалога, присвойте один класс, например, `input-with-dialog`.

```
var popup = {
    id_clicked : null, 
    openDialog : function(id){
    popup.id_clicked = id;
    $('#select_tag').dialog('open');
  }
}
$(".input-with-dialog").on("click", 
  function(){
    popup.openDialog(this.id);
  }
)
```

Тогда `id` нажатого элемента будет доступен через `popup.id_clicked`.

Answer (score 0):

Что если повесить событие onclick на все инпуты с классом `.input`:

```
<input id="oldtag" class="input" name="Tag[name]" value="..." type="text" required/>

<script>
    // когда происходит клик на любом инпуте с классом .input вызывается это событие
    $(document).on('click', '.input', function() {
        var input_id = this.id, // это id инпута на который кликнули
            value = this.value; // это его значение
        $('#select_tag').dialog('open'); // видимо вызов диалогового окна, я не очень понял
        // если нужно вставить значение кликнутого инпута  в другой инпут
        $('#other_input').val(value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это поможет мне в диалоговом окне `_tag.php` узнать `id` инпута

Comment: ну покажите кусок своего окна. где там нужно его узнать?

Comment: на данный момент в окне эта строчка `document.getElementById("oldtag").value = val;` записывает переменную `val` в значение `input id="old_tag" `. Но в ручную прописывать `"old_tag"` не подходит, нужно автоопределение

Comment: у вас на странице два инпута с одинаковым id='old_tag' что ли? короче мне задача все еще не ясна. сейчас обновлю свой ответ с объясняющими комментариями

Comment: я потом добавлю еще один ипут с id="new_tag". Так вот, мне нужно чтобы в диал. окне можно было определить из какого инпута оно вызвано

Comment: `$('#new_tag').val(value);`